# Cant get marker on map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm trying to set up a map but the marker won't show. This is the javascript for my Google map.

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=REMOVED"></script>

<script>

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    function initialize() {
    var pos = {lat: -33.911757, lng: 151.158454};

    var mapProp = {
    mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    center:pos,
    zoom:17,
    styles: [TOO MUCH CODE HERE SO I REMOVED IT. IT'S A SNAZZY MAP]
};

var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);

var markerImage = 'http://www.mapsmarker.com/wp-content/uploads/leaflet-maps-marker-icons/bar_coktail.png';

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: pos,
                map: googleMap,
                title: 'Snazzy!',
                icon: markerImage
});
marker.setMap(googleMap);

}
</script>
```

The HTML:

```
<div id="googleMap" style="width:600px;height:400px;"></div>
```

I can't figure out why the marker won't show. What's going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you passed div id  `'googleMap'`  to the marker's map property.
Instead you must passed initialized `map` variable. See the comment and edited code below.

```
var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp); //you must use this map variable
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: pos,
                    map: map, // map variable must be passed here, instead you passed googleMap
                    title: 'Snazzy!',
                    icon: markerImage
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using marker which is defined outside of you click function.

what you need to look at is the google maps api, and find out how to get the clicked marker id

marker is incrementing through the loop and will ALWAYS be the last marker created

or

Your code doesn't create a marker. You should add something like

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(51.54968,-0.16305), 
    map: map,
    title: "One title"
});
```